# Applying two functions to different values of the same column

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization, data.table

I have two functions that are used to display numbers:

```
comprss <- function(x) {
  div <- findInterval(abs(x), 
                      c(0, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12) )  # buckets of thousands
  digits <- 2
  if (!is.null(x) && !is.na(x) && abs(x)<1) {
    x <- ifelse(abs(x)< 0.0000001, 0, x) #very low values at 0 for display purposes
    x <- signif(x, digits)
  } else {
    paste0(signif(x/10^(3*(div-1)), 3), 
           c("","k","M","B","T")[div],sep="")
  }
}
```

and

```
reformat <- function(x, digits) {
  abs_x <- abs(x)
  x <- ifelse(abs_x < 0.0000001, 0, x) # Very low values set to 0 for display purposes
  x <- ifelse(abs_x >= 10^digits,
                    stringr::str_extract(as.character(formattable::comma(x)), "^[^\\.]+"),
                    signif(x, digits))
  return(x)
}
```

`comprss` is used to rewrite numbers with compaction suffixes (k for thousands, M for millions...)

`reformat` is used to write numbers with appropriate commas.

I have an object `data_test` which is a data.table object:

```
data_test <- data.table(Value = c(1, 12, 871, 1873, 87128, 0.125, 1.1652, 321.276, 17627.17012, 1, 12, 871, 1873, 87128, 0.125, 1.1652, 321.276, 17627.17012, 1, 12, 871, 1873, 87128, 0.125, 1.1652, 321.276, 17627.17012),
                        Unit = c("€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts"))
```

I want to apply `comprss` to `data_test` values whose unit is **not** in `c("pts","%")`, and `reformat` to `data_test` values whose unit is in `c("pts","%")`.

My problem is that both functions take `"numerical"` objects as arguments, and return `"character"` objects. If I apply one function to certain values, it transforms the vector into a character vector, so I can't apply the other function.

I created this intermediate function to solve my problem:

```
custom_function <- function(x, unit, digits) {
  if (!(unit %in% c("%","pts"))) {
    x <- comprss(x)
  } else {
    x <- reformat(x,digits)
  }
}
    
 x <- mapply(custom_function, x, unit, digits)
```

It does work but I repeat this operation a very large number of times and to huge data tables, and `mapply` is pretty slow.

How could I do it in a more optimized way? I mean using less memory and less time.

Comment: Avoid `ifelse`, `x[abs(x) <  1e-07] <- 0` will be much faster.

Comment: You don't need to write your own functions, `scales` has those functions. ```scales::label_number``` and ```scales::label_comma```.

Answer (score 2):

`scales` library has functions similar to what your custom functions are achieving. I am using those here, but you can replace them with your functions if needed.

```r
library(data.table)
library(scales)
```

We can subset the dataset based on the `Unit` column and apply the appropriate functions.

```
rbindlist(list(data_test[Unit == "€"][,
                Value := label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale(),
                                      accuracy = 0.1)(Value)], 
               data_test[Unit != "€"][,
                 Value := label_comma(accuracy = 0.1)(Value)] 
))
```

Or if we want to preserve the order, we can use `fifelse`:

```
data_test[, Value := fifelse(Unit %in% c("pts","%"),
                             label_comma(accuracy = 0.1)(Value),
                             label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale(),
                                          accuracy = 0.1)(Value)
                             )]
```

```
#>        Value Unit
#>  1:      1.0    €
#>  2:     12.0    €
#>  3:    871.0    €
#>  4:     1.9K    €
#>  5:    87.1K    €
#>  6:      0.1    €
#>  7:      1.2    €
#>  8:    321.3    €
#>  9:    17.6K    €
#> 10:      1.0    %
#> 11:     12.0    %
#> 12:    871.0    %
#> 13:  1,873.0    %
#> 14: 87,128.0    %
#> 15:      0.1    %
#> 16:      1.2    %
#> 17:    321.3    %
#> 18: 17,627.2    %
#> 19:      1.0  pts
#> 20:     12.0  pts
#> 21:    871.0  pts
#> 22:  1,873.0  pts
#> 23: 87,128.0  pts
#> 24:      0.1  pts
#> 25:      1.2  pts
#> 26:    321.3  pts
#> 27: 17,627.2  pts
#>        Value Unit
```

or with your custom functions:

```
data_test[, Value := fifelse(Unit %in% c("pts","%"),
                             reformat(Value, 1),
                             comprss(Value)
                             
)]
```

```
#>      Value Unit
#>  1:      1    €
#>  2:     12    €
#>  3:    871    €
#>  4:  1.87k    €
#>  5:  87.1k    €
#>  6:  0.125    €
#>  7:   1.17    €
#>  8:    321    €
#>  9:  17.6k    €
#> 10:      1    %
#> 11:     12    %
#> 12:    871    %
#> 13:  1,873    %
#> 14: 87,128    %
#> 15:    0.1    %
#> 16:      1    %
#> 17:    321    %
#> 18: 17,627    %
#> 19:      1  pts
#> 20:     12  pts
#> 21:    871  pts
#> 22:  1,873  pts
#> 23: 87,128  pts
#> 24:    0.1  pts
#> 25:      1  pts
#> 26:    321  pts
#> 27: 17,627  pts
#>      Value Unit
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know for these functions! Unfortunately, it changes the order of the values whereas I need the values to remain on their original row

Comment: @paulbouu `rbind` solution is probably faster, you could add row ids to your data and use those for reordering afterwards, but I don't think that'd be so efficient. Anyway, I added another approach with `ifelse` which preserves the order.

Comment: The problem with these functions is that we cannot chose the number of digits, for example, with `accuracy = 0.1`, we will get "89.7" for 89.732, which is what I want, but "0.0" for "0.01". And I don't want to have to set `accuracy` to 0.01 in order no to get "89.73" for 89.732

Comment: @paulbouu as I said, you can use your custom functions if you want. Or, wrap the `scales` functions in another `ifelse` to further format `Value` column. Anyway, I added a solution using your functions as well. This should address your problem. If you have a follow-up request, please consider posting another question.