# Applying two functions to different values of the same vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have two functions that are used to display numbers:

```
comprss <- function(x) {
  div <- findInterval(abs(x), 
                      c(0, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12) )  # buckets of thousands
  digits <- 2
  if (!is.null(x) && !is.na(x) && abs(x)<1) {
    x[abs(x) <  1e-07] <- 0 #very low values at 0 for display purposes
    x <- signif(x, digits)
  } else {
    paste0(signif(x/10^(3*(div-1)), 3), 
           c("","k","M","B","T")[div],sep="")
  }
}
```

and

```
reformat <- function(x, digits) {
  abs_x <- abs(x)
  x <- ifelse(abs_x < 0.0000001, 0, x) # Very low values set to 0 for display purposes
  x <- ifelse(abs_x >= 10^digits,
                    stringr::str_extract(as.character(formattable::comma(x)), "^[^\\.]+"),
                    signif(x, digits))
  return(x)
}
```

`comprss` is used to rewrite numbers with compaction suffixes (k for thousands, M for millions...)

`reformat` is used to write numbers with appropriate commas.

I have three vectors of the same length `x`, `unit` and `digits`:

```
x <- c(1, 12, 871, 1873, 87128, 0.125, 1.1652, 321.276, 17627.17012, 1, 12, 871, 1873, 87128, 0.125, 1.1652, 321.276, 17627.17012, 1, 12, 871, 1873, 87128, 0.125, 1.1652, 321.276, 17627.17012)

unit <- c("€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "€", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts", "pts")

digits <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

I want to apply `comprss` to values of `x` whose unit is **not** in `c("pts","%")`, and reformat to values of `x` whose unit is in `c("pts","%")`.

My problem is that both functions take `"numerical"` objects as arguments, and return `"character"` objects. If I apply one function to certain values, it transforms the vector into a character vector, so I can't apply the other function.

I created this intermediate function to solve my problem:

```
custom_function <- function(x, unit, digits) {
  if (!(unit %in% c("%","pts"))) {
    x <- comprss(x)
  } else {
    x <- reformat(x,digits)
  }
}
    
 x <- mapply(custom_function, x, unit, digits)
```

It does work but I repeat this operation a very large number of times and to huge data vectors, and `mapply` is pretty slow.

How could I do it in a more optimized way? I mean using less memory and less time (I need to keep the values order).

I had already asked the question for 3 columns of the same table, but now it is not the case anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-instantiate an empty-string vector, then do a simple indexing:

```r
out <- character(length(x)) # empty strings
out[!unit %in% c("pts", "%")] <- sapply(x[!unit %in% c("pts", "%")], comprss)
out[unit %in% c("pts", "%")] <- mapply(reformat, x[unit %in% c("pts", "%")], digits[unit %in% c("pts", "%")])
```

Side note: it would be far faster to allow `comprss` to work on vectors instead of needing `sapply` on them. Try:

```r
comprss <- function(x) {
  if (!length(x)) return(character(0))
  div <- findInterval(abs(x), 
                      c(0, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9, 1e12) )  # buckets of thousands
  digits <- 2
  ifelse(!is.na(x) & abs(x) < 1,
         replace(signif(x, digits), abs(x) <  1e-07, 0),
         paste0(signif(x/10^(3*(div-1)), 3), 
                c("","k","M","B","T")[div],sep=""))
}
comprss(x[!unit %in% c("pts", "%")])
# [1] "1"     "12"    "871"   "1.87k" "87.1k" "0.12"  "1.17"  "321"   "17.6k"
```

Comment: What about the `digits` input for `reformat`?

Comment: Add it as an argument, I just edited it in. (I don't have `formattable` installed so could not run _that_ expression.)

Comment: But `digits` is a vector, can I just put the vector as argument inside `sapply`?

Comment: Right, sorry ... see my (again) edit.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I tried many times to vectorize my functions but I get class errors because of the transformation `numeric` -> `character`...

Comment: I'm trying your code

Comment: I just noticed ... asking [nearly identical questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77580250/applying-two-functions-to-different-values-of-the-same-column) is often frowned upon, even more so when you get upvoted answers and you choose to not accept them. It's generally better to keep the discussion going (as long as it is not spiral dev). Please consider going back and accepting that answer.

Comment: But if it doesn't improve runtime nor memory it won't help anyone don't you agree?